# How do i dynamically iterate through a nested JSON and update all the values that are floating type

Tags: java, c#, json, api, testing

I am trying to do something like the below:

Round off all the values of a huge nested response and round off any values that are floating points to two decimal places. I am trying to recursively call the function but i guess the real problem is how do i update the original JSON object and return it finally once i am done changing all the values. Once i am in the recursion function, i would have lost the sense of how deep i am into the Nested structure so i really wont know where to update the original. 
So there are multiple levels of keys and values like i have update below
{ "Key1": "Bread",
  "Key2": 0.78,
  "KMey3": "08-12-2012 14:34",
  "Key4": {
     "name": "value1"
     "Trendline: { {Month=Jan, Point=10}}
                 {Month=Feb, Point=12}

so on .. .. 
  }
}

```
    public static Object ProcessJSON(Object obj)
    {
        Object temp = obj;
        if (!IsObjectLazyMap(obj))
        {
            if (isDecimal(obj))
            {
                obj.value = RoundOff(obj.value);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++)
                {
                    ProcessJSON(obj[i]);
                }

            }

        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: 'code'public static Object ProcessJSON(Object obj)
{
     Object temp = obj;
        if(!IsObjectLazyMap(obj))
         {
           if(isDecimal(obj))
     {
       obj.value = RoundOff(obj.value);
          }
        else 
     { 
       for(int i=0;i<obj.size();i++)
         {
          ProcessJSON(obj[i]);
         }
  }
   }
  return obj;
}

Comment: Please add your code to the question by using the "edit" link. That way you can format it nicely, and it will be easier to read.

Comment: why java and C# instead of Python and  C++

Comment: @Cecilia Sorry, first time here, added the code .. :)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Because the project currently i am working in is JAva. i am using Groovy script to udpate some scripts in my REadyAPI test suite. I am not sure python will be compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objective is only to find floating point results and round or truncate them, you could turn your JSON into a String and then create an InputStream based on that String to read it into a Scanner object.

```
String jsonString = obj.toString();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(stream);
```

After that you can find the float types using scanner.nextFloat()

You can use the exact output of that value to do a find and replace in your original string.

```
if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
    float myFloat = scanner.nextFloat();
    String myStringFloat = Float.toString(myFloat);
    //Do stuff to your float here.
    jsonString.replace(myStringFloat, newFloatValue);
}
return jsonString.JSONFunctionToTurnThisBackIntoAnObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `isFirst` flag to your method and set it to true when you first call it, then use false for all of the recursion

```
public static Object ProcessJSON(Object obj, boolean isFirstLevel) { 

    Object temp = obj; 

    if(!IsObjectLazyMap(obj)) { 

        if(isDecimal(obj)) {

            obj.value = RoundOff(obj.value);

        } else {

            for(int i=0;i<obj.size();i++) { 

                ProcessJSON(obj[i], false); 

            } 
        } 

    } 

    if (isFirstLevel) {

        // Your code

    }

    return obj;

}
```

Alternatively use an approach that doesn't use recursion:

```
public static Object ProcessJSON(Object obj) { 

    List<Object> objetsToProcess = new ArrayList<>();

    objetsToProcess.add(obj);

    while (objetsToProcess.size() > 0) {

        Object temp = objetsToProcess.get(0);
        objetsToProcess.remove(0);

        // Process "temp"
        // If it's another object that needs processed then use "objectsToProcess.add(temp);"

    }

    // post processing code

    return obj;

}
```

Comment: actuallly without recursion how will i go to deeper levels . there might be 5 levels of key value pairs in teh JSON response . and the decimal values might be at the level so i need to iterate there and update values there